# "A person reads thirty percent slower from a computer than from a printed document."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

**"A person reads thirty percent slower from a computer than from a printed document."** Is this sentence already sufficient?

So far, I've received two revisions:

1.) **"A person who reads from a computer is 30% slower at reading a printed document."**
      - I think this one really changes the context of the sentence.

2.) **"A person reading from a computer does so at a rate of thirty percent slower than when reading from a printed document."**
      - And this one seems a little wordy.

Comment: The first revision has the exact opposite meaning! I think the original is fine. Consider clarifying 'computer' to 'computer screen' though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is grammatical. However, it is also clumsy. I would instead write

> Reading speed when reading from a screen is 30% slower than when reading from a printed document.

The edits you received are both wrong. The first changes the meaning of the sentence to mean that in general, people who read from computers a lot are 30% slower when reading printed documents. The second introduces a grammatical error, *at a rate of 30% slower* is wrong.

Comment: 'Slower' rather than 'more slowly' in OPs post is controversial; in ELU terms a ? rather than a *. But I agree your revision is the best so far.

Comment: @TimLymington controversial? How? My point was that _at a rate of X slower_ is wrong. _X slower_ would be fine, a _slower rate_ would be controversial but might be acceptable. However, _at a rate of [...] slower_ is off since you cannot have _a rate of slower_.

Answer (score 0):

How about :
People read 30 % slower on screens than on paper.

or :
A person reads a digital document 30% slower than its paper version/edition.